# Difference between state variable and state function in thermodynamic?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

I think these two terms are sometimes used as synonyms and other times as different concepts. Can some explain what is the difference?
An example would be good.

Also, can state variable be the state function at the same time? Eg. in ideal gas let's take pressure P... is it a state variable or state function? What about volume V and temperature T?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pressure $P$ is state variable when we specify equilibrium state of a system by giving numerical value of $P$.

Pressure $P$ is a state function when we discuss how the above value depends on other state variables like $V,T$.

Comment: That makes sense.. So can we say in other words that: "state variable" is something that we take as independent variable, while "state function" is something that depends on previously selected "state variables" where this dependence is given in the equation of state for the particular thermodynamic system. Would this statement be correct?

Comment: @matori82, yes, I think that's the way people use these terms. Of course, value of every state function can be used to define a state variable. Usually the symbols for the function and the corresponding variable are adopted to be the same.

Comment: @JánLalinský So for example if we write $U=f(S,V,n)$ then $U$ is a state function and $(S,V,n)$ are state variables whereas if we write $V=f(U,S,n)$ then $V$ is a state function and $(U,S,n)$ are state variables?

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas if you are able to express $V$ as function of $U$,$S$,$n$ then yes. But this is not guarranteed by existence of function $f$ that gives internal energy by $U=f(S,V,n)$. There may be two or more different volumes associated with same $U,S,n$.

Comment: @JánLalinský So we need to show that $f$ is invertible. But I don't know how we can do it for 3 variables. I mean $U=f(S)$ can be inverted and consider entropy as state function. How about starting  from Euler's theorem? Because $U=f(S,V,n)$ is first order homogeneous we can write: $$U=TS-pV+μn $$ So we could say $$V=\frac{1}{p}(U+TS-μn)$$ which is 1-1.

Comment: Even if $f$ is homogeneous function of $S,V,n$ of first order, and we can express $V$, this does not mean $V$ is function of $U,S,n$ only. You expression for $V$ contains other symbols.

Comment: @JánLalinský The differential is using fundmanental relation of thermodynamics (ignoring number of particles for simplicity) $$dV=\frac{T}{p}dS-\frac{1}{p}du$$ It is also true that $$\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)_U=\frac{T}{p}$$ and $$\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial U}\right)_S=-\frac{1}{p}$$ Doesn't this prove that V is a state function? What am I getting wrong?

Comment: The expression $dV$ you gave is fine for simple systems that have constant $n$. However nothing implies $V$ is function of $S,u$. Therefore nothing implies the derivatives $\partial V/\partial S$ make sense. If there is no function in the first place, there is no derivative.

Answer (score 0):

State variables are called the coordinate of the system,
Which usually govern the state of the system.
And state function is a conditional type of state variable that only tells us the current state of a system.